# Update alert dialog title in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I used alert dialog with title in fragment activity.I created alert dialog in separate class.

I have to update title name, when i click the button inside the alert dialog???

Below shows alert dialog code

```
public  class ViewCartDialog 
{
 Activity activity;
 Cursor cursor;
 public static AlertDialog.Builder builder;
 public ViewCartDialog(Activity activity)
 {
  this.activity=activity;
  cartDialog();
 }
 public void cartDialog() 
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
      //  builder.setIcon(R.drawable.shopping_cart);
   cursor = DBCatalog.getCursor();
        builder.setTitle("My Carts"+"("+cursor.getCount()+")");
        LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
     View cartview = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list, null);
     final EditText custcode=(EditText) cartview.findViewById(R.id.cust_codefield);
     final EditText custname=(EditText) cartview.findViewById(R.id.cust_namefield);
     custcode.setOnTouchListener(new DrawableClickListener.RightDrawableClickListener(
       custcode) {
   @Override
   public boolean onDrawableClick() {
    new Customer(activity,custcode,custname);
    return true;

   }

  });
        ListView cart_lv=(ListView) cartview.findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        CartAdapter cartadapter=new CartAdapter(activity, R.layout.cart_listitem, cursor);
        cart_lv.setAdapter(cartadapter);
        builder.setView(cartview);
     builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Place Order",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
        builder.show();
 }
}
```

Comment: can you please post alert dialog code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code in dialog class:

**Static** AlertDialog alert;

alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();

Then use the following code in Fragment activity

**ViewCartDialog.alert.setTitle(" ");**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
builder.show();
```

use this

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
      alert.show();
```